# How do I set default page for my website if the index file is located inside a couple of more folders in htdocs?

Tags: mod-rewrite, web-hosting

When I load my website I want the default page to be loaded but it is located inside two more folders in htdocs. I tried changing .htaccess but it did not work as I expected. This is my directory structure:
htdocs\hotel-management-repo\hotel-app\index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What rule did you apply in the .htaccess? Have you tried something like:

```
 RewriteRule ^index.php$ hotel-management-repo\hotel-app\index.php [QSA,L]
```